# Getting around the 32-relationship-per-table limit in Access

Tags: ms-access, database-design, schema

I am attempting to build a database for inventory control using a large number of tables and enforced relationships, and I just ran into the 32-relationship (index) limit for an Access table (using Access 2007).

Just to clarify: the problem isn't that the Employees table has 32 explicit indexes. Rather, the problem is the limitation on the number of times the Employee table can be referenced in `FOREIGN KEY` constraints. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE Employees (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL UNIQUE)
;
CREATE TABLE Table01 (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employees (employee_number))
;
CREATE TABLE Table02 (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employees (employee_number))
;
CREATE TABLE Table03 (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employees (employee_number))
;

...

CREATE TABLE Table30 (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employees (employee_number))
;
CREATE TABLE Table31 (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employees (employee_number))
;
CREATE TABLE Table32 (employee_number INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES Employees (employee_number))
;
```

An exception is thrown on the last line above, "Could not create index; too many indexes defined.

What options do I have to work around this limitation?

I've heard that creating a duplicate table with a 1:1 relationship is one method. I'm new to database design, so please correct me if I'm wrong; but given a table Employees with 31 indexes, I would create a table Employees2(with one field?) with a 1:1 relationship to Employees and relationships to this new table from any remaining relations in which EmployeeID is a foreign key. What's the best way to ensure the second table is populated alongside the first?

Is there another approach?

Based on the lack of information available, it seems this may be a rare problem with a properly-designed database, or the solution is common knowledge. Forgive the noob!

**Update**: Immediate consensus is that my design is borked or far too ambitious. This could very well be the case. However, I'd rather have a general design discussion within a separate question, so for the sake of argument, can someone answer this one? If the answer is simply "Don't ever do that" I'll have to accept it.

Comment: I think you will find your overall design is faulty.  This particular limit doesn't get met otherwise.

Comment: "overall design is faulty"  is wrong.  I've had a number of systems hit this problem.

Comment: @Tony:  Ah!  Thanks for that insight.  I must point out however that our inquirer says he is "new to database design" ....

Comment: I've never encountered anything close to this. I have to think the design is denormalized, e.g., with repeating fields having RI enforced on them.

Comment: And another point: Relationships and indexes are two orthogonal, though related, subjects. Relationships can be defined only between indexed fields, but you can have indexes on fields that have no RI defined on them. I would suggested trying Tony's utility to see if you have duplicate indexes to eliminate. If you're running with Access defaults, you likely do have duplicate indexes (e.g., because of the table designer adding indexes to ID fields, or because of the hidden indexes created when you add a relationship overlapping with indexes you've created by hand).

Comment: @David @Smandoli I'll be linking from this question to a new one based on my schema in the following week. We can discuss normalization there, but to give you something to harp on: The Employees table I refer to is actually called Contacts, and is comprised of every individual our company is in touch with, and is related to other tables such as ContactsByAccount (e.g., if a contact is associated with our company, they are an employee). This Contacts table is a foreign key in a number of transaction tables such as InvoiceDetail, ReceiverDetail, etc, to record who requested an order/who took it.

Comment: @David Yes, I built a good part of the database with those horrible defaults turned on, but have since gone back through and removed the non-primary-key indexes. The only ones remaining besides those are those associated with foreign key relationships, which is to say they aren't visible in the index editor.

Comment: You might find though that performance will suffer on reports and such by removing too many indexes.   In one particular situation adding an index to a Yes/No field on a Job table with less than a 1000 records made a query which also included a table with 800K records about 10 times as fast.

Comment: Well, the question has gotten five answers and the average vote score for this is -1.6.   That's a chuckle.

Comment: I thought that your database design might be sensible and you have outgrown the database, but according to all the negative response I got to my advice the database is outstanding and your database design sucks... :P

Comment: The average score of answers has risen and is almost reached zero!  Go team!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> ... I would create a table
>   Employees2(with one field?) with a 1:1
>   relationship to Employees and
>   relationships to this new table from
>   any remaining relations in which
>   EmployeeID is a foreign key.

That is workable.  Presumably your main table might have an Autonumber field as the primary key, or you generate an index number.  Your Employees2 table obviously must echo that.

> What's the best way to ensure the
>   second table is populated alongside
>   the first?

That depends somewhat on how you are adding records.  But in general, of course you must comply with the rules for integrity.  This usually comes down to appending to tables in the correct order and ensuring each record is saved before trying to add a related record elsewhere.

Comment: Great, my main concern was that my approach to this problem was valid (misdirected or no). I should be able to set up a form to add new records to Employees and a copy of their corresponding ID to the second table.

Comment: Good.  I trust it will go well.  If you want to post on the basic table scheme ("How would you approach ...") and flesh out the details, I'd be very interested in what you get.

Answer (score 3):

I've run into this limitation a number of times with my apps.  And I can assure the other posters that my apps are very well designed.

One problem is that Access creates indexes due to relationships and lookup fields that aren't viewable on the main index property box but they are accessible via DAO collections.   These indexes are frequently duplicate indexes to indexes you have created as well.

I have a tool consisting of several forms you import into your BE MDB that allows you to remove the duplicate indexes.   As I haven't yet made this available on my website please email me for it.

Comment: Have you run into the problem because of the hidden and automatically-created indexes? That is, have you ever encountered it with only the indexes you intended to add?

Comment: David, not sure I understand your question.  Whenever I've encountered this problem there have been both indexes Access created behind the scenes and indexes I created.  So I removed the indexes I had created which got me around the problem.   Although in one particular app that wasn't enough.

Comment: One advantage of using SQL DLL in ANSI-92 Query Mode is you can use the keywords NO INDEX in a FOREIGN KEY declaration to prevent the creation of the implicit index. Now that's converted you all into SQL DDL fanatics, right? ;)

Comment: But why would you want to?  Chances are exceedingly high that you would want an index on a foreign key for performance purposes.

Comment: A few phrases and the tone of your comment comes across as sarcastic.

Comment: If I were getting acquainted with MS Access via Stack Overflow, I'm afraid I'd conclude Access is snarky and easily offended.

Comment: @Tony: I'll try again. Why would you want to create no index? For all the usual reasons, with which I'm sure you are familiar (e.g. index selectivity), and so that you do not have to subsequently drop it. Why did the SQL Server team add the 'fast foreign keys' feature to the Jet 4.0 engine? AFAIK this is not publicly documented and I cannot speculate. More interestingly, why do Access MVPs not use the features added to the engine in the last decade? i.e. shouldn't MVPs at least be steering the engine feature set around to those that regular/power Access users would use?

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest just not defining all the relationships/indexes to implementing a 1:1 relationship to get around it. Neither solution is optimal, but the later is going to create a much higher maintenance burden and data anomaly potential.

I am not going to decry the design as quicky as some of the others, but it does have me intrigued. Could you list the fields of the employee table that are foreign keys? There is a good liklihood that some normalization is in order and maybe some of the smart people on SO could make some design suggestions to work around the issue.

Comment: I have this same interest in the scheme.  I still think a fresh post would be appropriate

Answer (score 1):

It is hard for me to believe that an Employee table would need 32 indexes; if it actually does you should consider migrating to at least SQL Express.

Comment: or anything else that isn't Access

Comment: I agree with ocdecio, having an employee table that requires 32 relationships seems strange, however we don't know your req's. +1 for migrating to SQLServer, I believe you can link an Access front end to the SqlServer backend (but have never tried it)

Comment: Agreed--Access isn't exactly my first choice. But supposing I'm stuck with it for now? I'd like to understand the options I have within this system so that I can make a fully-informed decision to migrate.

Comment: "Access isn't exactly my first choice" ... what would be, then?

Comment: @Smandoli SQL Server is obviously more robust and better-suited to large databases.I'm sure there are a number of better options out there, but the question still remains: how would I get around the limit in Access? See the update to my question. If it's not a valid question, I can live with that.

Comment: I would suggest that 32 indexes is more likely to represent a design error than to be a correct implementation, and failing to correct the design error and migrating to a database that supports more index is just going to exacerbate the problem in the original design.

Comment: @rmeador: Platform bashing isn't going to solve this guy's problem.

Comment: @David-W-Fenton if you think that something like 24 relation + 8 index is a design error, maybe that you have never seen how medium-complexity application are made (130 table, 200 relations, 500 indexes and 250k lines of code) (the fact that MS Access may not be the best choice, is another thing :-))