# Database design to reduce dependency on "look up fields"

Tags: ms-access, database-design, schema

I challenge you to solve this puzzle!  I am creating a database to track customer orders.  These orders can be quite complicated with lots of options so I need to design the database in order to not hit the 32-relationship-per-table rule in Access.  The requirements are as follows:

Orders: (needs roughly ~20 fields of header data for things like name, incoming date, shipping date, frame, etc.).

Selection Fields: there are ~60 different Selection Fields associated with each order to define scope of work (Different type of inspections, disposition of each disassembled part, what type of part to re-install, how to prepare components for shipping, etc..) Would like for these to be drop down fields in the orders table...

Options: each Selection Field has between 2-6 options.  Each of these options have descriptions, and also indicate which operations should be performed.

Operations: a list of all possible operations that should be included depending on the options selected above.  Each operation has ~5 fields of info associated with them (op number, descriptions, hours to complete, etc.)

I currently have an excel file with a few hundred lines of VBA code that sorts through all the options and creates drop down boxes for me...I now use it to create quotes, work orders and all kinds of things.  It has been one of those projects that starts out small and transforms into a beast.  The problem is, I now like the beast and rely on the beast but it is now time to find the beast a new home where it can have its own space to breath a little.

I appreciate your input!

Comment: Did you  see this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1138580/getting-around-the-32-relationship-per-table-limit-in-access?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. You do not need foreign keys ("relationships") or indexes to query or update.
2. You can store the same information with fewer foreign keys per table by replacing a table by new tables that each hold a projection of it (ie only some of its columns) as long as the new tables each have among their columns those of some one candidate key (PK/UNIQUE) of the original table and they collectively account for all the columns of the original table. You reconstruct the original table by joining the new ones together on the candidate key.
3. To minimize changes to query code referencing the original table you can define a view whose expression is that join.